# PHPMyAdmin Errors: #126 - Incorrect key file for table

Tags: php, xampp, mariadb

I've just installed XAMPP on Win10 (Installer), but get errors in PHPMyAdmin before I've even done anything:

I get the 'you're signed in as root, without a password, you should change it, so I click on User Accounts and I get this:

```
Error

Static analysis:

5 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 52)
Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 110)
Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 177)
Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 245)
Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 311)

SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit

(SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`user` )
UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`db` )
UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`tables_priv` )
UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`columns_priv` )
UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`procs_priv` )
ORDER BY `User` ASC, `Host` ASC

MySQL said: Documentation
#126 - Incorrect key file for table '.\mysql\db.MYI'; try to repair it
```

Comment: do as the error says. "try to repair it". your mysql files are corrupted somehow.

Comment: What (and how) exactly am I repairing.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html

Comment: It's ok, I've gone thru every Schema and repaired all tables that I can and it seemed to work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
USE mysql;
CHECK TABLE db;
# When it comes back and tells you to REPAIR it,...
REPAIR TABLE db;
```

Ditto for any other MyISAM tables that were messed up during the last power failure.

Answer (score 0):

Had the EXACT same problem with phpMyAdmin 4.5.0 out of the box with XAMPP. I just updated to the latest phpMyAdmin (4.5.1) in my case from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/

I used this guide to do the update: 
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/update-phpmyadmin/

As a side note, I have real issues with hacking around and repairing tables on something that should work out of the box. Each to their own, I suppose.

Comment: I'm totally with you. It should work fine with minor configuration out of box.